# How to use function inside a class python

Tags: python, oop

I want to use a function implemented inside a class as followed:

```
class calcul:
    def func(a,b):
        return log(a/b)
    def sec_func(c,d):
        out = func(c,d)
        return out
```

I've tried to initiate the function:

```
class calcul:
    def __init__(self):
        self.func(a,b)
    def func(a,b):
        return log(a/b)
    def sec_func(self,c,d):
        out = self.func(c,d)
        return out
```

however, I get 'func is not defined' as output

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: What is ```a``` and ```b``` in ```self.func(a,b)```? and It's better to use ```Calcul``` as class name(first letter uppercase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably missing the `self` as first argument of your functions. Else you should declare them as `@staticmethod`. What you probably want to do is

```py
class Calcul:
    def func(self,a,b):
        return log(a/b)
    def sec_func(self,c,d):
        out = self.func(c,d)
        return out
```

Answer (score 1):

You would create a class like so.

```
#define the class
class Calcul:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        #pass becuase no attributes to store
    def func(self, a, b):
        return log(a/b)
    def sec_func(self,c,d):
        out = self.func(c,d)
        return out

#create a new instance of the class
calc_obj = Calcul()

#call the function using the class variable you have just defined.

ans = calc_obj.func(1,2)
ans1 = calc_obj.sec_func(1,2)
```

Comment: I get an error when running this: `func() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: my bad, i've edited it. `func` needs the self input parameter